# OpenGL FXAA issues

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I am a Computer Science Student and I am currently doing a 2d Game for my Coursework.
I know that it's kind of unnecessary, but I tried to implement the FXAA algorithm for the AA of the game. The shader I am using is this one, because I thought using just a simple frag shader would be alright. I can also be found [on Github](https://github.com/demoscenepassivist/SocialCoding/blob/master/code_demos_jogamp/shaders/fxaa.fs).

```
#version 120
#define FXAA_REDUCE_MIN (1.0/128.0)
#define FXAA_REDUCE_MUL (1.0/8.0)
#define FXAA_SPAN_MAX 8.0
uniform sampler2D sampler0;
uniform vec2 resolution;

void main(){
   vec2 inverse_resolution=vec2(1.0/resolution.x,1.0/resolution.y);
   vec3 rgbNW = texture2D(sampler0, (gl_FragCoord.xy + vec2(-1.0,-1.0)) * inverse_resolution).xyz;
   vec3 rgbNE = texture2D(sampler0, (gl_FragCoord.xy + vec2(1.0,-1.0)) * inverse_resolution).xyz;
   vec3 rgbSW = texture2D(sampler0, (gl_FragCoord.xy + vec2(-1.0,1.0)) * inverse_resolution).xyz;
   vec3 rgbSE = texture2D(sampler0, (gl_FragCoord.xy + vec2(1.0,1.0)) * inverse_resolution).xyz;
   vec3 rgbM  = texture2D(sampler0,  gl_FragCoord.xy  * inverse_resolution).xyz;
   vec3 luma = vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114);
   float lumaNW = dot(rgbNW, luma);
   float lumaNE = dot(rgbNE, luma);
   float lumaSW = dot(rgbSW, luma);
   float lumaSE = dot(rgbSE, luma);
   float lumaM  = dot(rgbM,  luma);
   float lumaMin = min(lumaM, min(min(lumaNW, lumaNE), min(lumaSW, lumaSE)));
   float lumaMax = max(lumaM, max(max(lumaNW, lumaNE), max(lumaSW, lumaSE))); 
   vec2 dir;
   dir.x = -((lumaNW + lumaNE) - (lumaSW + lumaSE));
   dir.y =  ((lumaNW + lumaSW) - (lumaNE + lumaSE));
   float dirReduce = max((lumaNW + lumaNE + lumaSW + lumaSE) * (0.25 * FXAA_REDUCE_MUL),FXAA_REDUCE_MIN);
   float rcpDirMin = 1.0/(min(abs(dir.x), abs(dir.y)) + dirReduce);
   dir = min(vec2( FXAA_SPAN_MAX,  FXAA_SPAN_MAX),max(vec2(-FXAA_SPAN_MAX, -FXAA_SPAN_MAX),dir * rcpDirMin)) * inverse_resolution;
   vec3 rgbA = 0.5 * (texture2D(sampler0,   gl_FragCoord.xy  * inverse_resolution + dir * (1.0/3.0 - 0.5)).xyz + texture2D(sampler0,   gl_FragCoord.xy  * inverse_resolution + dir * (2.0/3.0 - 0.5)).xyz);
   vec3 rgbB = rgbA * 0.5 + 0.25 * (texture2D(sampler0,  gl_FragCoord.xy  * inverse_resolution + dir *  - 0.5).xyz + texture2D(sampler0,  gl_FragCoord.xy  * inverse_resolution + dir * 0.5).xyz);
   float lumaB = dot(rgbB, luma);
   if((lumaB < lumaMin) || (lumaB > lumaMax)) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(rgbA,1.0);
   } else {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(rgbB,1.0);
   }
}
```

The problem I ran into is, that whenever I turn the shader on my screen is flipped upside down... How do I solve this? It's probably because of the Orthographic Projection, but I am just a student, so I can't come up with a solution.

Comment: Just a side note: I am using the fxaa shader on a fullscreen texture right now for testing issues (just a metalslug screenshot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a texture coordinate problem. Use `1-V` instead of `V` to flip your mirrored image.

```
vec2 correctedFragCoord;

correctedFragCoord.x = gl_FragCoord.x;
correctedFragCoord.y = resolution.y - gl_FragCoord.y;
```

Then replace `gl_FragCoord` by `correctedFragCoord` in the shader.

Comment: sounds like an approach, but I still have a lack of glsl, I am reading through a book right now, but how would you implement 1-V in the complex frag shader I posted? Would be really helpful, thanks in anticipation...